# How to add AND operator in Dynamic query in SOQL query

Tags: soql

```
queryStr+=clsList[0].G_Color_Code__c!=null ? ' AND G_Color_Code__c=\''+clsList[0].G_Color_Code__c+'\' AND \''+G_Color_Code__c=null+'\'': ' AND G_Color_Code__c=null' ;
```

Here it throws an error expression cannot be assigned

Answer (score 2):

This conditional processing can result in:

```
something AND G_Color_Code__c='somevalue' AND 'badbadbad'
```

Basically your:

```
'\' AND \''+G_Color_Code__c=null+'\''
```

is incorrectly structured since this is looking to add a literal evaluation of `G_Color_Code__c = null` which won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
    queryStr+=clsList[0].G_Color_Code__c!=null ? ' AND G_Color_Code__c=\''+clsList[0].G_Color_Code__c+'\' AND G_Color_Code__c=null': ' AND G_Color_Code__c=null' ;
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Answers that are simply code dumps tend to be less useful than those that take some time to explain what's going on. They also usually generate a lot of back-and-forth in the comments ("that didn't work", "try this instead", etc...) that make it hard for other people to follow. At the very least, you should explain what the difference between your solution and the original code is. The most useful answers tend to explain what the issue is, how to fix it, and why the fix works. You can [edit] your answer if you'd like to improve it.